# Filtering items in a view using a CAML query

Tags: 2010, web-services, caml-query

I'm having trouble querying SharePoint in such a way, as to combine a view results with my own CAML query inside a WCF service. It seems `GetItems` ignores my query, and just returns all the items in the view regardless.

Here's the sample code I'm trying out right now:

```
    public bool Test()
    {
        using (SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site)
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
            {
                var list = web.Lists["Test"];
                var caml = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Field2\" /><Value Type=\"Boolean\">1</Value></Eq></Where>";
                var view = list.Views["TestView"];
                var query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = caml;
                List<SPListItem> viewWithCamlItems = new List<SPListItem>();
                SPListItemCollection results;
                do
                {
                    results = list.GetItems(query, view.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper());
                    results.Cast<SPListItem>().ToList().ForEach(i => viewWithCamlItems.Add(i));
                    query.ListItemCollectionPosition = results.ListItemCollectionPosition;
                } while (results.ListItemCollectionPosition != null);
                var camlOnlyResults = list.GetItems(new SPQuery() { Query = caml }).Cast<SPListItem>().ToList();
                var x = viewWithCamlItems.Count;
                var y = camlOnlyResults.Count;
                return x == y;
            }
        }
    }
```

The list in question has only 2 columns: Field1 and Field2, and both of these are Yes/No columns. The view displays only those rows where Field1 is True. At the moment of writing this question, I've only got 1 row in the list where Field2 is True; considering the `camlOnlyResults` contains just that one row I think the CAML is correct, and I'd expect `x` and `y` to be equal...

However, I get all rows in `viewWithCamlItems` inside the view...

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The reason I'm using paging in one case and not the other, is because the view might have a small row limit, while the default `SPQuery` has a row limit of `uint.MaxValue`, which is plenty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
results = list.GetItems(query, view.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper());
```

You should just use

```
results = list.GetItems(query);
```

Otherwise you get the where clause from the view as stated in the Remarks to `public SPListItemCollection GetItems(
    SPQuery query,
    string viewName
)`

> The properties of the view that is specified by the viewName parameter
>   override the properties that are specified in the query object that is
>   passed through the query parameter. For example, if the query object
>   includes a  tag that specifies only items containing a
>   particular column value, while the view specifies to return all items,
>   this method retrieves all of the items

Comment: Aye, I missed that part initially. Is there any way to combine CAML filtering with that provided by a view?

Comment: You can pass the view to the constructor [`SPQuery(SPView view)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms413177) which will initialize several of the properties in the SPQuery with the corresponding fields from the view, but in most cases this isn't what you want as the enduser may change the query in ways which may cause problems for your code. So usually it's best to build the entire query in code, but as always it depends on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `<Value Type=\"Bool\">1</Value>`, rather than `Boolean` when querying on boolean fields.

For `camlOnlyResults` it looks like you're casting the list to a single element, which is why the result of ToList contains only a single element.

Comment: Since `var camlOnlyResults = list.GetItems(new SPQuery() { Query = caml }).Cast<SPListItem>().ToList();` returns the correct results I think the CAML is OK.